# Border a div with clear cuts

Tags: css

Here's a box with some borders:
http://jsfiddle.net/wywmLshc/

```
.box{
    height:300px;
    width:900px;
    border-left: 15px solid black;
    border-top:5px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

There's a 45 degree angle where the black and red border crosses. I don't want this. I want only a black border to the left and the red one starts next to it (not any above it). Do I need to make another div to accomplish this? Or is there some neat CSS-trick that solves the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how the border is rendered. To achieve what you want, use pseudo elements instead:

```css
.box {
    height:300px;
    width:900px;
    border-top:5px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    position:relative
}
.box:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:15px;
    top:-5px; /* .box border-top value */
    bottom:-5px; /* .box border-bottom value */
    left: -15px; /* .box:before width */
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or use `box-shadow`:

```css
.box {
    height:300px;
    width:900px;
    border-top:5px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: -15px 0 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't `left: -15px` on the pseudo element be better, as it's now occupying 15px of the div's width?